# Levene's Test and residuals vs. fitted plot lead to different interpretations about heteroscedasticity

Tags: r, anova, residuals, diagnostic, levenes-test

I am performing a one-way ANOVA in R with the following data:

| Cu | Day | CC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cu1 | 49 | 30934500 |
| Cu1 | 49 | 26860125 |
| Cu1 | 49 | 46524750 |
| Cu10 | 49 | 15272561 |
| Cu10 | 49 | 31601659 |
| Cu10 | 49 | 17627634 |
| Cu100 | 49 | 3718127 |
| Cu100 | 49 | 4941416 |
| Cu100 | 49 | 6230801 |

The ANOVA aims to determine if CC changes (on average) depending on Cu (three levels: Cu1, Cu10, and Cu100) or, in other words, to check if Cu exerts an effect on CC.
The code I used was:

```
    analisis_varianza <- aov(CC~Cu, data=dia_49)
    summary(analisis_varianza)
```

And, to check the homoscedasticity assumption:

```
   leveneTest(CC~Cu, data=dia_49)
```

The problem is that Levene's test suggests that variances are homogeneous (p=0.5424), while the residuals vs fitted plot for the ANOVA clearly indicates that the variance is not homogenous:

[image]

On which should I rely on and why?

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's a bad idea to rely on tests of normality for taking decisions. In this case, the Levene's test p-value is probably high because you have a very small sample size. On the other hand, if you have very large sample sizes, the test will show significant deviations from normality even when it's not a problem for inference.

In short, graphs are much more informative than tests.

Here's a very useful thread: [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2492/121522)

Comment: Ok, I understand, I will check the link, thanks!